# Require the latest .jar for Salesforce API v32

Tags: apex, visualforce

we are trying to connect to salesforce api currently using version 2 of the api, and some fields are not visible. We have noticed the issue seems t be resolved wit the version 32.

We are running a java based system to connect to the api. Can you pleae advise / provide us with the .jar version allowing us to connect to version 32 of the API ?

Comment: Isn't there such thing as a .jar to be used by java applications ? is there a way to get a .jar file instead of using the ANT program ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1 How to build the Partner.jar API file

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_code_set_up_client.htm

## 2 Going further , There might be some issue as I have seen found during the same inside the thread :

http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?171969-Update-SalesForce-Jars For which As a resolution you can also refer http://sforcehacks.blogspot.com/2013/04/building-partnerjar-api-file.html

Answer (score 0):

You can login to your Salesforce organization and download the Salesforce Ant tool from Setup -> Develop -> Tools -> 
Force.com Migration Tool

[image]